# How should I understand "beckon" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I learned the following sentence from *The Economist*.

> Perfectly efficient electric cables, more powerful generators and motors, magnetic levitation and a host of other technological wonders **beckoned**.

I have looked it up in the dictionary:

> **beckon**
>   intransitive verb
>   1 : to summon or signal typically with a wave or nod
>   2 : to appear inviting : ATTRACT

But I am still not able to understand the sentence above with either explanation of "beckon". How should I understand this word and the sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply plug the dictionary definition that fits into the sentence:

> Perfectly efficient electric cables, more powerful generators and motors, magnetic levitation and a host of other technological wonders [appeared inviting].

Or to put it another way, we were seduced by the prospect of these technological wonders.

Answer (score 6):

It's the second use. Those technological wonders *attracted* or *appeared inviting* to observers, or developers, or to some other group of people not mentioned in the sentence.

Answer (score 3):

The implication is that the combined prospect of all these factors was highly attractive - ie. the sentence could be rephrased as

> "*The prospect of* perfectly efficient electric cables, more powerful generators and motors, magnetic levitation and a host of other technological wonders *was highly attractive*."

Answer (score 2):

The second usage is appropriate, e.g.:

> The shop window decorations beckoned.

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly #2.  I didn't read the article, but from this sentence I'd guess it's referring to either a very new technology or one just out of reach that scientists are working towards.  Your sentence would then means that the applications of this discovery (or discovery-to-be) are very attractive, giving the scientists a very strong incentive (a more metaphorical/anthropomorphic summoning) to make and apply said discovery.